# Can you rearrange natural numbers so sum of first $n$ is divisible by $n$ for every $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math

> Can you rearrange natural numbers so sum of first $n$ is divisible by $n$ for every $n$?

I want to prove this by induction, if we rearrange first $n$ numbers we can always choose an integer so sum is divisible by $n+1$. But how can I prove every number will be used?

Example: $1, 3, 2, 6, 8$ and so on...

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want every natural to appear exactly once in the list? (and also $n$ always divides sum of first $n$ in the list?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes

Comment: Based on tens of thousands of terms [in Python](https://repl.it/repls/MulticoloredWeepyWebsite), I conjecture the add-the-smallest-legal-term greedy algorithm you've obviously tried satisfies the following result, stronger than what you seek: the least positive integer absent from the first $n$ terms is at least $n/2$, so contrapositively any $n$ appears in the first $2n$ terms. I don't know how to prove this, but I suspect trying to prove it is a viable approach.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you, I will try to prove it.\

Comment: It's claimed at http://oeis.org/A019444 that the greedy algorithm works. No proof there, but links to the literature where I expect a proof can be found.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proof:

Let $a_1 = 1$, that is base of induction.

Inductive hypothesis: We have valid array $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$. Now let $x$ be the smallest number which is not in array yet. Let $a_{n+2} = x$, by chines reminder theorem, we know there exist $a_{n+1}$ so $n+1|\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i$ and $n+2|\sum_{i=1}^{n+2}a_i$. Now we have valid array with length $n+2$ and we can guarantee all natural numbers will be in array, for some large enough $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The greedy algorithm (select the smallest distinct number that works) does work, and you will get [OEIS A019444](https://oeis.org/A019444). One of the references there – [Venkatachala (2009)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Venkatachala/venkatachala2.html) – proves that it is an *involution* (stronger than permutation) of the natural numbers.

Comment: Not just a permutation, in fact, but an involution. It's a long paper no answer here can really summarize, but it's a worthwhile read, finding lots of interesting properties the sequence has.